# C# DataGridView Drag and Drop behaviour?

Tags: c#, datagridview, drag, behavior

I have a question about the drag and drop behaviour of a windows forms datagridview.
In my scenario a user has to drag single rows from a datagridview and drop it in a listview.
When I start the application this works fine but after I dropped one row i have to click twice onto the datagridview and then I have to click a third time to do a drag and drop operation.
This is not userfriendly.
How can I achieve that after a drag n drop operation it will be possible to do the next drag and drop without having to click onto the datagridview? (click and hold mousebutton to drop in a single click after the last drag and drop)

Here is a sample code:

```
private void dataGridView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.DoDragDrop(dataGridView1.SelectedRows, DragDropEffects.Move);
        dataGridView1.Focus();
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0];
    }

    private void listBox1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
    }

    private void listBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString());

    }
```

I already tried to fix this with datagridview1.Focus() but it doesn't help.

Further info:
Datagridview is set to readonly, multiselect disabled and fullrowselection.

Thank you!

Comment: Your drag drop is started not from the user dragging a row, but simply clicking any mouse button.  That means when you come back to it, those first clicks are starting DD ops rather than selecting a row etc.  Also, you appear to be dragging *all* the selected rows, but just the dragged one.

Comment: Yes thats true but SelectedRows can only hold on Row because multiselect is turned off.
Is it possible when I come back to the datagridview to select a row and start the draganddrop with a single click?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `MouseDown` which is used for basic functionality of the `DataGridView` you should rather use `MouseMove`.

```
private void lvDrop_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    var rows = e.Data.GetData(typeof(DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection)) 
                as DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection;

    if(rows.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach(DataGridViewRow row in rows)
        {
            lvDrop.Items.Add(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
        }
    }
}

private void lvDrop_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
}

private void dgvDrag_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        dgvDrag.DoDragDrop(dgvDrag.SelectedRows, DragDropEffects.Move);
    }
}
```

**Results in this behaviour:**

[image]

**ToDo's**

Care for invalid incoming drops.